# Verifiying a digital signature in a Plutus script

Tags: plutus, script, validator

Is there a function like [signedBy](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger/html/Ledger-Crypto.html#v:signedBy) that I can call in a Plutus script to verify a digital signature?

Comment: So are you looking for a type like this: verifySig :: Signature -> PubKey -> Bool? (signedBy without the tx)?

Comment: Well the problem is that a Plutus script calling signedBy will not compile because signedBy is not inlinable. So I need a function that can be called by a Plutus script. The TxId argument isn't a big deal because I can always get that from the ScriptContext.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [function](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/b778f9abbe172177b579badf83b899ee05fda2e0/plutus-ledger-api/src/Plutus/V1/Ledger/Contexts.hs#L233) to verify signature from a validator